# Is it possible to create a custom node in node-red that can be dragged on to the work space only once? Is there any default node with such behaviour?

Tags: node-red

I've integrated node-red dashboard in my MEAN application i want only one instance of node to drag on to the node-red work space. how to restrict the node to use it only once on dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to limit the number of instances of a specific node on the canvas.

The best you could do is to write the node is such a way that all the state is global for the node and multiple instances all work with the same state.